# Change Timestamp with 'Date Time' to 'Date'T'Time'

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a csv like this:

```
ID;Query;Time;Value(optional);Url
12;"Query 1";2004-02-12 01:31:14;1;"Url 1"
12;"Query 1";2004-02-13 08:38:23;;"Url 2"
12;"Query 2";2004-02-13 08:38:31;;"Url 3"
12;"Query 3";2004-02-13 08:38:42;1;"Url 1"
```

but what I want, is a **T** instead of a space for the Time-Column; like this:

```
ID;Query;Time;Value(optional);Url
12;"Query 1";2004-02-12T01:31:14;1;"Url 1"
12;"Query 1";2004-02-13T08:38:23;;"Url 2"
12;"Query 2";2004-02-13T08:38:31;;"Url 3"
12;"Query 3";2004-02-13T08:38:42;1;"Url 1"
```

If you know other tools, which can solve this issue, it would be great. You can assume, that the Year is fix 2004, but month and day are not fix. The CSV is over 2 GB therefore something like Excel can't handle this.

I tried using SED, like:

```
cat pleaseHelpMe.csv | sed 's/2004-..-.. /T/p'
```

but the result is that it overrides the pattern but I would like to override just one specific char.

Result: `12;"Query 1";T01:31:14;1;"Url 1"`.

Comment: I have restored the Original question of OP in question, OP had samples with his/her attempts. Later OP was keep adding results of solutions provided, so removed that part only here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}/){
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr," ")
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) arr[1]"T"arr[2] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '
##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}/){
##Using match function of awk to match yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss regex here in current line.
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr," ")
##Splitting sub string of matched regex in match function into array named arr
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) arr[1]"T"arr[2] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
##Printing sub string from 1 to RSTART-1 arr 1st element T arr 2nd element sub string of rest line.
  next
##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1
##1 will print current line. Basically that line which does not match regex.
' Input_file  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: i update the Question with the well formated output of your algorithm

Comment: @Root_DE, for your shown samples it worked fine for me.

Comment: In the mose Cases it works like a charm, but if the querrys contains something like the regex, than these are changed also. Is there any way, to update this scipt to not change the querrys (or the order of the rows). E.g. to match the first yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss pattern after the second not escaped quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you find yourself talking about "fields" (aka "columns") you should be using awk, not sed or grep, since awk is designed to operate on fields:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {sub(/ /,"T",$3)}1' file
ID;Query;Time;Value(optional);Url
12;"Query 1";2004-02-12T01:31:14;1;"Url 1"
12;"Query 1";2004-02-13T08:38:23;;"Url 2"
12;"Query 2";2004-02-13T08:38:31;;"Url 3"
12;"Query 3";2004-02-13T08:38:42;1;"Url 1"
142;"207 ad2d 530";2006-04-08T01:31:04;;""
```

Comment: unfortunately i dont have any experience with awk, can you explain why this works; if one of the querry contains "\;" this affect awk

Comment: I'm just telling awk to use `;` as the field separator and then doing a substitution on just the 3rd ;-separated field, just like if you could do s/old/new/ with sed on a specific field. It's not that it'd affect awk, but it would break the script I've written in awk. It'd just mean writing a different script in awk to take that into consideration. Again, if the sample input/output in your question isn't truly representative of your real data then you've got to fix it to be more realistic as what you show us in that example all we have to go on and test with to come up with a solution.

Comment: I added more example, the Querys can be anything (like google Querys)

Comment: Please stop adding extra lines to the bottom of your question and simply update the sample input/output already present at the top of your question to include those lines your adding and any other relevant examples. Make it as simple as possible for us to help you. **Think** about what might be problematic - at a glance I don't see any examples where a quoted field can contain `"`s or newlines, so think about whether or not either of those can happen and, if so, include them and anything else you can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Update from OP on example contents shows that a more thorough regex is needed:

Since the year `2004` is fixed here, that can be used like this:

```
sed -e 's/2004-\([0-9]*-[0-9]*\) /2004-\1T/'
```

which is like before, but now the captured group is bigger.

Again

```
echo "12;"Query 1";2004-02-12 01:31:14;1;"Url 1""|sed -e 's/2004-\([0-9]*-[0-9]*\) /2004-\1T/'

12;Query 1;2004-02-12T01:31:14;1;Url 1
```

---

Use the replacement for (digit)(space) to (digit)T like this:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\) /\1T/'
```

Because each line has only one place with a space followed by a digit, this should suffice.

The `\([0-9]\)` captures the digit, which is put back using `\1`

Using this I get

```
echo "12;"Query 1";2004-02-12 01:31:14;1;"Url 1""|sed -e 's/\([0-9]\) /\1T/'

12;Query 1;2004-02-12T01:31:14;1;Url 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Querries can contain somehting like this, i forget to mention this, here ist something frome the real Dataset:
`142;"207 ad2d 530";2004-04-08 01:31:04;;""`
->
`142;"207Tad2d 530";2004-04-08 01:31:04;;""`

Comment: I see. So this got wrongly replaced. Not a big problem. I will make an edit.

Comment: thank you, I think that is what i want; but if any Querrys contain something like "2004-03-17 was a good day" they would be changed to :/; therfore its maybe not what i needed

Comment: Yes, they will change. You will have to give precise description of your file for using sed. If your file is too complicated, you can try using sed like replacements in vim by visually selecting the relevant text. They'd not become `:/` but `was` -> `Twas`.

Comment: I added more example, the Querys can be anything (like google Querys)